# apache kafka, как отследить/детекитровать событие - необработанные консюмером сообщения удалены retention политикой

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Бывают случаи, когда консюмер по каким-то причинам не обработал сообщения, а retention политика уже эти сообщения удалила, и хотелось бы реагировать на это событие, например переотправить сообщения.

Собственно вопрос, как отследить/детекитровать событие "необработанные консюмером сообщения удалены ретеншен политикой" ?
Далее по тексту это событие буду называть Событие X.

Из того что я тестировал, если необработанные сообщения удаляет ретеншен политика, то на консюмере
с настройкой `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG= "none"` происходит эксепшен `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException`.
Можно ли на этот exception закладываться, как на Событие Х, или этот exception может кидаться в других случаях ?
Может быть есть другой способ отследить Событие Х ?